# pinescript : fill 2 trackprice lines background with color

Tags: pine-script

I want to fill 2 trackprice lines range with color.

Is there anyway to do it in pinescript ?

```
D1_clr = color(#fbc02d)
// ---
D1_ohlc_high = plot(timeframe.isintraday ? prev_1_High : na, title="Yhigh", trackprice=true)
D1_ohlc_low  = plot(timeframe.isintraday ? prev_1_Low  : na, title="Ylow",  trackprice=true)
// ---
fill(D1_ohlc_high, D1_ohlc_low, color=color.new(D1_clr)
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of any way to do it. You can fill the last bar with this code:

```
//@version=4
study("Trackprice fills", "", true)
prev_1_High = highest(10)
prev_1_Low  = lowest(10)
D1_clr = color(#fbc02d)
D1_ohlc_high = plot(timeframe.isintraday ? prev_1_High : na, title="Yhigh", trackprice=true, offset = 1)
D1_ohlc_low  = plot(timeframe.isintraday ? prev_1_Low  : na, title="Ylow",  trackprice=true, offset = 1)
fill(D1_ohlc_high, D1_ohlc_low, color=D1_clr, show_last = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help.

It's not really the desired effect.

What do you think about place : 1) "hline" to the top, 2) "hline" to the bottom, 3) place them at the beginning of the day, 4) fill between.
How can find the beginning of the day, to in fact "plot(hline)" at this time ?

Regards.

Comment: Edit : i mean "line" (horizontal ray), instead of "hline".

Comment: Won't work because [`hline()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_hline) doesn't accept price values that change (requires *input float*).